# What are the advantages of using the zurb foundation gem vs using sass standalone on windows?

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

I'm fairly new to foundation but it's something I've been trying to integrate into new and existing projects at work.  My team develops mostly on macs but for one of our major projects the development environment is on a vm running windows.  I've used the foundation gem on one project on my mac but I'm not sure how to approach the windows barrier. I've considered using something like [scout](http://mhs.github.io/scout-app/) on windows to compile the scss files.  I'm not aware of the full functionality of the foundation gem.  What features would I be losing if I went with something like scout instead of the foundation gem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the "windows barrier" by walking around it. I found Scout, the Ruby installer for windows, and other possible solutions too far outside the workflow I am used to. I solved this particular problem by using sass/compass and the zurb-foundation gem on my mac and using samba to connect the windows vm as a volume drive.

```
Finder > Go > Connect to Server > smb://my-vm/c$
```

You can then easily watch any directory with a config.rb file. The network lag in my scenario was minimal.

```
cd /Volumes/c$/some-directory
compass watch
```